# Inability to find a required service_manager gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I'm working on some cucumber tests from The Cucumber Book. I've got the code that tries to use a transaction processor and there is a file with the following code:

```
require 'service_manager'

ServiceManager.start
```

This is on Mac OS X 10.6.8 using Ruby 1.9.2. When this file executes, I get the following:

```
no such file to load -- service_manager (LoadError)
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/gpollice/MyCucumber/ATMBookExample/features/support/services.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
```

The service_manager gem is installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems as are other gems that the application uses. Until I added the code for this iteration, there were no problems. I've looked for reasons why the gem is not found and just can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the value of `$LOAD_PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a load path issue.

Is require "rubygems" invoked prior to this require statement?

Also, if you're using bundler, you have to add this gem to your Gemfile, as bundler attempts to sandbox your dependencies. If you're using bundler, try the following after adding the gem to the Gemfile:

```
bundle exec rake cucumber
```